# Efficient way to count combinations of records with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

Given a table of orders and a related table of items in those orders, I need to find the the number of orders with each possible combination of SKUs. I'm doing this in Magento, but this is really just a SQL question, as I'm working directly at the database level.

Here are the relevant portions of each table:

**sales_flat_order**

```
| entity_id | int(10) unsigned |   -- primary key
```

**sales_flat_order_item**

```
| order_id  | int(10) unsigned |   -- foreign key to order table's entity_id
| sku       | varchar(255)     |
```

I've been able to pull the data I want using a subquery and the MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` function, but I'd like to know if there is a way of doing this that is more efficient and/or that works without proprietary functions. Here's what I have currently:

```
SELECT skulist, COUNT(skulist)
FROM (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sku ORDER BY sku) skulist
    FROM sales_flat_order orders
    JOIN sales_flat_order_item items ON orders.entity_id = items.order_id
    GROUP BY order_id
) skulists
GROUP BY skulist;
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: This GROUP_CONCAT approach was feasible because there are only a handful of SKUs sold by this merchant; however, it's not scalable and thus not generalizable, so that's partially what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, in fact, the best way to do this, with one small caveat.  You can make your query more efficient by removing the `join`:

```
SELECT skulist, COUNT(skulist)
FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sku ORDER BY sku) as skulist
      FROM sales_flat_order_item items
      GROUP BY order_id
     ) skulists
GROUP BY skulist;
```

As for not using database-specific functions.  That is hard.  Most database have a way of doing `group_concat(distinct . . .)`.  As far as I can tell, no two do it the same way (ok, not really true because the Postgres-derived databases do use the same syntax, but close enough).

In standard SQL, you can easily find all permutations of *n* items, for a given *n*.  However, I can't think of a way to do it for all combinations in a database-independent way.

Comment: Good point about the join. That's what happens when you evolve a query a little bit at a time and don't go back to reanalyze your starting point. Thanks.